# How to ship/include a generated file with ISO?

Tags: centos, operating-system, rpm, rpmbuild, rar

I am trying to build an ISO where I have some prebuilt RPMS. I have another file which is dynamically generated and I want the ISO to include it and when that same ISO is installed, it should be placed in /usr/bin folder. I know one way is to make a RPM of the same file and package that RPM as part of the ISO so that when the other RPMs are installed, this RPM will also install the file in proper location. But is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit ISO with UltraISO.

Comment: I'm particularly interested to know if there is any directory where I can place the file so that it automatically picks up the file when ISO is being installed. Editing the ISO after it's built is not in the scope for me.

Comment: You can add me in Telegram@MonsieuRuss for details.